# Is CSRF possible in Aurelia if XSS attacks are mitigated?

Tags: javascript, security, xss, csrf, aurelia

- I have an aurelia app with .net web api.
- I communicate to the api via ajax calls.
- I authenticate using a bearer token which is stored in the browser localstorage.

I've heard that this is insecure as the token can be retrieved through an XSS attack. There is only one input on the website where a user can add comments. However I'm binding the comment value using string interpolation e.g.:

```
${commentText}
```

My understanding is that it is impossible to inject html into a binding like this.

Is there an XSS attack possible with an aurelia site if no html bindings are used? And if not, am I therefore protected by CSRF attacks if the token is inaccessible?

The only examples I've seen online, is if a user can inject html (through some form of input) into a page in a XSS attack revealing the token to the attacker. I haven't been able to replicate that with the string interpolation binding.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a full answer to your question, but Aurelia does HTML escape any text that is interpolated in to a template like with `${commentText}`.

The only exception to this rule is when you use the `innerhtml` binding like this `<div innerhtml.bind=“htmlText”></div>`. In that case we don't do *any* sanitization of the text being sent as HTML. That's up to you.

Comment: Just adding some info to Ashley's answer... You can use a sanitizer value-converter when binding `innerhtml`, e.g `<div innerhtml.bind=“htmlText | sanitizeHTML”></div>`. You can also create your own value-converter that uses a more powerful sanitizer. More information at http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/cheat-sheet/5

Comment: Thanks for the response, I've temporarily added a innerHtml binding to expose csrf vulnerability. I'll implement a antiforgery token to prevent csrf, then remove the innerHtml once I know its secure. If in the future I do use innerHtml/html bindings I'll use the santizer value-converter suggested. Thanks